# Which Instance type support to host RestComm in AWS

Tags: restcomm

I have tried to setup Docker in AWS EC2 Micro instance.
I have managed to install successfully but I am not able to access from public DNS ?

Is there any problem with instance type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least a large type of instance